# how to set CSS for MPDF in yii2 on generating pdf file

Tags: php, css, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I am using `yii2 basic` and I need to generate a pdf report file which is styled with CSS file, I get the pdf well but CSS is not working on the generated file. Here is how I have implemented.

in my `controller.php` file

```
 public function actionPrintReport($student_id,$exam_id,$total_subjects,$exam_date){
        $model = new Results();
        $examReportData = $model->getExamReport($student_id,$exam_id,$exam_date);
     
        $htmlContent = $this->renderPartial('_report',
        [
            'model' => $model,
            'total_subjects' => $total_subjects,
            'examReportData' => $examReportData
        ]);
        $pathfile = "Student_exam_report";
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'tempDir' => Yii::getAlias('@runtime/') . 'mpdf2/tmp',
            'format' => 'A4-L',
            'margin_right' => 5,'margin_left' => 5,
            'defaultFont' => 'Calibri',
        ]);
        $stylesheet = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.Yii::getAlias('@web').'\css\exam_report.css'.'"/></head>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlContent, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
        $mpdf->Output($pathfile, 'I');
    }
```

The `_report.php` file is located in `view/` with the below minimal code

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
?>

<div class="container" style="width: 100%">
   <div class="leftpan">Left Pan</div>
   <div class="rightpan">Right Pan</div>
</div>
```

And CSS file is located at `project_folder/web/css/exam_report.css` with the minimal code like this.

```
 .rightleft{
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    border-style: dotted dashed solid double;
}
.rightpan{
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
    border-style: dotted dashed solid double;
}
```

I have stacked here for two days :), I would appreciate for your support.

Comment: Are you using kartik-mPDF?

Comment: @InsaneSkull yes I am using Kartik-mPDF

Comment: You can use `cssFile` property while creating Pdf Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "cssFile" option for external css files. In my case the bootstrap css file that is included in the plugin was not working so I created my own in the web folder. You have to check the path of the file as well when adding.

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
          'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
          'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
          'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
          'filename' => '/backend/web/invoices/invoice.pdf',
          'destination' => Pdf::DEST_FILE,
          'content' => $content,
          'cssFile' => 'css/invoicetemplate.css',
          'cssInline' => '.heading{font-size:18px}',
          'options' => ['title' => 'Invoice'],
        ]);
```